# What is com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

`com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.HttpURLConnection` seems to get used instead of `java.net.HttpURLConnection` (which I use in the code) when I'm profiling using Android Studio's profiler.  What is it and where can I find the source code?

I'm targetting API 23 (both `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`) with `minSdkVersion = 18`.

Comment: I've edited your question for clarity.   I added some code formatting.  I also some additional relevant tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling "android profiler httplurlconnection" leads me to this site:

[Inspect network traffic with Network Profiler | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/network-profiler)

> The Network Profiler displays realtime network activity on a timeline,
>   showing data sent and received, as well as the current number of
>   connections. This lets you examine how and when your app transfers
>   data, and optimize the underlying code appropriately.
>
> ...
>
> Currently, the Network Profiler supports only the HttpURLConnection and OkHttp 
>   libraries for network connections.

So, this class replaces `java.net.HttpURLConnection` when the profiler is running such that it can intercept and analyse network traffic.

[Android Studio is an open source project, see this SO question for links](https://stackoverflow.comquestions/22420726/is-android-studio-an-open-source-project)

Comment: Thank you, I was just wondering why I can't jump to source (button is grayed out) from the profiler window... Was too specific in my googling. I'll try to find the source in Google's repos as indicated in that question.